# How to tag Links with the OBJR tag in pdfmake?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdfkit, pdfmake

For pdfs to comply with 508c pdfs it needs to be tagged as a Link and have a child tag called Link - OBJR that enables technologies to property recongnize the link and handle it correctly. [What it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDWmZ.png)

Been trying to implmement the OBJR tag in pdfmake for a while and have gotten nothing. Adding tags by just adding another structure name Link - OBJR obviously didn't worked. Tried adding content to the OBJR tag and didn't work too. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.